# jquery how to get the status message returned by a ajax call of type post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apache, http

**javascript**

```
    $('#send').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            'url': $('#url').val(),
            'type': 'post',
            'complete': function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                var msg = "Status: " + jqXHR.status + " (" + jqXHR.statusText + " - " + textStatus + ")<br />";
                msg += jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders().replace(/\n/g, "<br />");

                $('#results').html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
```

**php**

```
    header("HTTP/1.0 200 Some message here");
    flush();
    exit();
```

**Results**

```
Status: 200 (OK - success)
Date: Wed, 07 Dec 2011 21:57:50 GMT 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Connection: Keep-Alive 
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6 
Content-Type: text/html 
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
```

**Question**

How do I get the "Some message here" part of the header?

**http**

[http protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)

> 6.1 Status-Line
>
> The first line of a Response message is the Status-Line, consisting of
>   the protocol version followed by a numeric status code and its
>   associated textual phrase, with each element separated by SP
>   characters. No CR or LF is allowed except in the final CRLF sequence.
>
> ```
>    Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure that's standard compliant for HTTP...

Comment: Yup, it is oddly enough.  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1  Only the code is required to be a specific code.  (Edit: At least in HTTP 1.1.  Finding 1.0 now..)

Comment: Just send your own custom header with that message.

Comment: @Xeon06 it is, I've added a link.

Comment: Well, it's valid if it's 200 (success) not 200(success).

Comment: @Corbin - the space is missing in the javascript so the formatted result is missing it, but that has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: @Corbin, Justin, huh, neat, didn't know that.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Was thinking that the Results section were the headers as viewed through Firebug or Chrome debug panel or something.  Didn't realize it was JavaScript formatting it that way and not the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. It's `jqXHR.statusText`.

```
$.get("test.php").complete(function(jqXHR) {
    console.log(jqXHR.statusText);
});
```

Just tried it out in Chrome with your exact PHP code.

Comment: jqXHR.statusText is returning `OK` for me, not `Some message here`

Comment: Chrome is the browser, Apache is the server

Comment: @Xeone06 - see my edit, updated my code and response to include `jqXHR.statusText`

Comment: Huh, well I have the same exact configuration. Maybe some obscure Apache setting. I'll update your post with more relevant tags to get people to come and see.

Comment: @Xeone06 - This works you javascript, but only for .get, not for a full ajax call with a `post` type :( in fact it works in a full ajax if I just a get rather than a post. I'll have to update my question.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried `xhrobject.getResponseHeader()` yet? [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) say it's also available there. If you don't know the header's name, try `getAllResponseHeaders()`.

Also, can you see that message in your browser's debugging console (network tab, connection headers)? If it's not there, it will hardly be available from js.

Comment: Read the post, not just the question title.