# How to get "textStatus" with jQuery .ajaxError()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqxhr

If I handle jQuery AJAX errors using `fail()`, I can use `textStatus` to provide a nice error message to the user:

```
$.get("/some_script.php")
.done(function() 
{ 
  // It works!
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
{
  switch(textStatus)
  {
    case 'timeout' :
      alert("Timeout");
    break;
    case 'parsererror':
      alert("Corrupted data")
    break;
    case 'error':
    case 'abort':
    default:
      alert("Unknown error");
    break;
  }
});
```

But when I use the `ajaxError()` global error handler, `textStatus` is not available:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) 
{ 
  ...
});
```

I checked the `event`, `jqXHR` and `ajaxSettings` objects to see if `textStatus` is hiding inside them, but had no luck. `thrownError` doesn't help me also.

All I want is to make `ajaxError()` tell me what kind of error occurred: timeout, parsererror, error or abort, just like `fail()` does.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: *"All I want is to make ajaxError() tell me what kind of error occurred: timeout, parsererror, error or abort, just like fail() does."* isn't that in the `thrownError` param, not `textStatus`?

Comment: In any event, you can get the status code if available through the jqXHR, which would handle any http-based errors, otherwise thrownError is all you've got.

Comment: @KevinB [is right](http://jsfiddle.net/72xtstkk/) - if you inspect the console you'll see `thrownError` returns what you are looking for. Also, `jqXHR.statusText`.

Comment: @KevinB, no. thrownError gives me HTTP error text, if available. If the connection had a timeout, thrownError doesn't tell me that. If I use $.getJSON for example, and the result is not JSON parseable, textStatus gives me parsererror, it's WAY better than anything else I ever used.

Comment: that makes no sense. I think you've got them swapped.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery how to get the status message returned by a ajax call of type post?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422932/jquery-how-to-get-the-status-message-returned-by-a-ajax-call-of-type-post)

Comment: There's nothing more available to you than what is given to you through the arguments. You can get the status code, and the text status, which will be "timeout" for timeouts. http://jsfiddle.net/72xtstkk/5/

Comment: @KevinB: but fail() does tell me when there is a parse error or timeout. Did you try that? I will create a jsfiddle as soon as I can.

Comment: Sorry, i updated my comment. it DOES give you a timeout message on timeouts. I can't test parseerrors in jsfiddle. See latest jsfiddle in above comment.

Comment: Here it is with invalid json. it doesn't say parseerror, but it's pretty damn close. http://jsfiddle.net/72xtstkk/8/ `SyntaxError: Unexpected token N(…)`

Comment: @KevinB: thanks for that, and it can serve as a workaround if there's no other way, but `fail()` provides a much better and precise information on what happened.

Comment: Then use .fail. unfortunately you're bound by the methods you use. An ugly workaround would be to create a wrapper for all ajax requests that attaches your own .fail to each and every one of them.